# How to get an specific field data from cloud fire store database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am able to access data document data but unable to access further field data of card like email.
getting error on .get() function.

[image]

**Function**

```
exports.StripeSource =functions.firestore.document('data/{card}/tokens/{tokenid}').onCreate(async (tokenSnap,context) => {
  const user_id = context.params.card;
  console.log('Document data:', user_id);
  var customerdata;
  const snapshot =  firestore.collection('test').doc('card');
  return snapshot
      .get()
      .then(doc => {
        if (!doc.exists) {
          console.log('No such User document!');
          console.log('Document data:', doc.data().email);

        } else {
          console.log('Document data:', doc.data());
          console.log('Document data:', doc.data().email);
          return true;
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {

        console.log('Error getting document', err);
        return false;
      });
  });
```

I run a code and get this error in console

```
[![TypeError: snapshot.get is not a function
    at exports.StripeSource.functions.firestore.document.onCreate (/srv/index.js:13:8)
        at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:131:23)
        at /worker/worker.js:825:24
        at <anonymous>
        at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)][2]][2]
```

Comment: What do you see when you console.log(snapshot)? My assumption would be that the test collection doesn't have a document called "card". But if you do firestore.collection('data').doc('card'), I'd expect you to reach the doc you want.

Comment: issue resolved thanks saglamcem I was making some other mistake. stay blessed

Comment: I found no issue in your code as I run same code. rerun the code and make sure you are putting same field name.

Comment: thanks @DanishMahmood actually I had the almost similar issue.

Comment: Glad to know you solved it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to read/write from/to Firestore in your Cloud Function you need to use the Admin SDK and you have to do:

```
const snapshot =  admin.firestore.collection('test').doc('card');
```

instead of

```
const snapshot =  firestore.collection('test').doc('card');
```

---

Note that you need to import the  Admin SDK module using Node require statements. Add these lines  to your index.js file:

```
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and setup triggers.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Firestore.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
```

---

Note also that calling the variable `snapshot` may lead to some errors (i.e. mixing-up variable type due to wrong naming).

By doing `admin.firestore.collection('test').doc('card');` you define a [`DocumentReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.html). It's by calling the asynchronous [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.html#get) method that you get a [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.html).

---

Finally, do not forget to return a Promise or a value in your Cloud Function (you don't return anything if `!doc.exists`). It's worth watching the 3 videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the Firebase video series: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/

Comment: thank @Renaud. I resolve the issue I am getting email from this field I had some other. but still I am unable to access number value to I am getting above email by doing this doc.data().email but not able to get doc.data().payment

Comment: Can you update your question to show exactly where you have this `payment` field? In your question you only show a document `card` in the `data` collection and this document has only one field. It is very difficult to understand where is this `payment` field since we don't have a full view of your Firestore DB, as you have.

Comment: really thanks renaud I always see to help others. my payment issue also resolved actually stripe payment accept value in cent so I have to convert my number value by multiply with 100 and now everything is fine. stay blessed

Answer (score 0):

Nicely explained by @Renaud. Just a little change.
To make the code work instead of `admin.firestore` , I had to use `admin.firestore()` with the bracket.

Just a summary here.
Instead of

```
const snapshot =  firestore.collection('test').doc('card');
```

First we need to import firebase-admin:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();
```

and use it like this:

```
const snapshot =  admin.firestore().collection('test').doc('card');
```

Working code for this problem. You can copy-paste this, it will run.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

exports.StripeSource =functions.firestore
  .document('data/{card}/tokens/{tokenid}')
  .onCreate(async (tokenSnap,context) => {
  const user_id = context.params.card;
  console.log('Document data:', user_id);
  var customerData;
  var customerEmail;

//I have to assign the a value to customerData, to use it outside. 
//That's why I made a little change and added await here
  const snapshot = await admin.firestore()
      .collection('test')
      .doc('card')
      .get()
      .then((doc) => {
        if (!doc.exists) {
          console.log('No such User document!');
          console.log('Document data:', doc.data());

        } else {
          console.log('Document data:', doc.data());
          console.log('Document data:', doc.data().email);
         //Assigning value to customerData here
          customerData = doc.data();
          customerEmail = doc.data().email;
          return true;
       }
     })
      .catch((err) => {

        console.log('Error getting document', err);
        return false;
    });

//Now the value of customerData or customerEmail can be used anywhere
       console.log(customerData, "customerData Extracted");
       console.log(customerEmail, "customerEmail Extracted");
       
 });
```

Comment: Please explain your solution. Answers which do not have an explanation and are only code get flagged as low effort.